# Loading Local JSON file using Ajax, IE9 and Access denied

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to load in a local json file using the following ajax call through jquery

```
$.ajax({
          url: langFile,
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          error: function(jqXHR, Status, ErrorThrown) {
            alert("Could not load file: " + ErrorThrown);  
          },
          success: function (response) {
            // do stuff with response
            localStrings = response;
          }
        });
```

It works as expected in firefox but when I try to load in the file in IE9 I just get "Access denied", I have tried everything I could find on google but have not managed to solve this issue. I tried to move over to JSONP but could not make this work because it kept giving me syntax errors :( The script should get the json from the local file and then put the content of the json into a variable called localStrings.

The json file looks like this:

```
{
"Header1": "List1",
"Header2": "List2"
}
```

Is there anyway to get this to work in IE9?

Comment: Local as in "localhost" or as in "file://" from a folder on your machine?

Comment: sorry missed that, as in file on my machine. The langFile variable is defined to "json/test.json" at the moment.

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Are you using a local copy of jQuery or from a CDN?

Comment: I am using the following:
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: I strongly suggest setting up a web server and testing there, even if it is just to http://localhost/. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx Some other threads have noted that updating to jQuery 1.8.1 resolved the issue for them. There are many things it could be, file system permissions, IE security permissions, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be able to run as a file on the local machine so moving it to a webserver is not a possible solution. The 1.8.2 version just passes me a "No Transport" error

Comment: The most common cause of the No Transport error is cross-domain requests for which you would need jsonp. It can still be an issue with the security settings of IE.

Comment: did you add ?callback to the URL when attempting jsonp?

Comment: Yes I added the &callback? and the I had the json wrapped in a function called "?" I did not manage to get it to read the json correctly leaving me with a syntax error..